# Why does "for" sound more appropriate than "during" in "I couldn't do anything for the rest of the day"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

> I couldn't do anything **for/during** the rest of the day.

I know that *for* sounds correct, perhaps because "the rest of the day" is a finite chunk of time like "one hour" or "one week".

However, I am struggling to explain to my colleague (who speaks English as a second language) why *during* can't be used instead.

Comment: Because [most native Anglophones would say "**for**"](during the rest,for the rest), it sounds better, more natural. There's no _grammatical_ reason not to say "**during**".

Comment: But you could say, "*during* the remaining hours of the day."

Answer (score 2):

"During" indicates that something is happening at the same time as some other ongoing action. Notice that this includes the implication that something is *actively happening.* So you might say you were doing something *during* the baseball game. For example, "I was knitting a sweater during the baseball game." But you would not say that something DIDN'T happen *during* the baseball game, because *something not happening* is not an ongoing process, and does not require *any* time at all.

"I couldn't do anything" is a simple statement of non-action; it requires no duration, and so it does not require the use of the word "during." "For" is the way we summarize the entire period of time (the rest of the day) in a single lump, without emphasizing the ongoing duration of it.

To reiterate, the two words indicate a difference between action and non-action, but even more importantly, they also refer to different ways of looking at the *period of time* involved. *During*, which really means "within the duration of," typically refers to an *event* or an *action* (such as "the baseball game"), *which occurs within or delineates a period of time*, rather than any period of time itself. "For" refers to some period of time itself ("for the entire year," "for a whole week"), rather than events or actions.

Comment: @johnMlandsberg Slightly nit-picking, but you could, for example, say that something *didn't happen during* if you were discussing when it did happen (e.g. *That didn't happen during the game: it happened immediately afterwards*)

Comment: @TrevorD I agree with you, and it's not nit-picking. I would say the usage in that case _does_ require the reference to duration (_it didn't happen any time within the time span of the game_) and so _during_ is the way to say it.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg - I think your second paragraph is more on target than the first.  "I couldn't do X during the baseball game" sounds perfectly fine to me, even though it reflects a non-action.  I think it's more about the specific/finite duration of the baseball game versus the vaguer timeframe involving the rest of the day.

Comment: @Lynn Interesting point, Lynn, and I agree. But notice how a rephrasing of the reference to the game would influence our choice of "during" vs. "for": "I couldn't do X for the duration of the game." "I couldn't do X for the whole time the game was on." Yes, you can choose "during" in these sentences, but I think the inclination goes in the direction of "for" simply because the reference in these sentences is to time, rather than to the event itself, even though the duration is exactly the same, and as definite, as when we refer to the game rather than the time of the game.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg - Yeah, there's some subtle distinction here but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bill points out, **for** is more *natural sounding* (in this case) than **during**. There are many examples of grammatically correct structures that we refrain from using. For example: [I eat](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/sentencetext.htm#Simple). As far as grammar goes, this is a valid sentence. But it just doesn't sound that natural or *right* (unless you happen to want to state that eating is one of the things you routinely do).

So it wouldn't be technically correct for you to say, "it *can't be* used," but it might be safe to say "it *should not* be used."

And for helping your colleague to accept this fact, refer him to this ngram: [image]

Comment: That may not be an accurate ngram. Well thought-out search terms produce good results- as *for the rest of the* search attempts, I'd be careful using them.