# Do I always need "for" before time?

Tags: prepositions, time

I would like to know if I always need "for" to mention time. Could you teach me when I should use "for" and when I shouldn't?

(Background of this question: When I said "I slept for 7 hours last night" to a friend, he asked me whether it was 4 hours or 7 hours. He got confused.)

Examples

1. I played the guitar for 1 hour yesterday.
2. I work for 8 hours per day.
3. I waited for 2 hours.
4. I want to sleep for 7 hours every day.

Comment: No, you don't need "for" in any of those cases.  In #1 using "for" is probably more idiomatic, but you wouldn't upset very many people if you left it out.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/60566/371882 and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111539/why-does-for-sound-more-appropriate-than-during-in-i-couldnt-do-anything-f.

Comment: I would use  _for_ in all those sentences, though in some contexts I might omit it from (2) and (3).